# Unable to set the background colour of a UIView subclass used inside a UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiview, drawrect

**Problem:**

The custom view's background colour for each cell in my `tableView` always uses the initial colour set when declaring my *statusColour* variable, and the colour set dynamically in `cellForRowAt IndexPath` is always ignored.



**This is my UIView subclass:**

```
class SlantedView: UIView {

    var path: UIBezierPath!
    var backgroundColour: UIColor!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func slantedView() {

         // Drawing code
         // Get Height and Width
         let layerHeight = CGFloat(90)
         let layerWidth = CGFloat(300)

         // Create Path
         let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()

         //  Points
         let pointA = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
         let pointB = CGPoint(x: layerWidth, y: 89)
         let pointC = CGPoint(x: layerWidth, y: layerHeight)
         let pointD = CGPoint(x: 0, y: layerHeight)

         // Draw the path
         bezierPath.move(to: pointA)
         bezierPath.addLine(to: pointB)
         bezierPath.addLine(to: pointC)
         bezierPath.addLine(to: pointD)
         bezierPath.close()

         // Mask to Path
         let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
         shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
         layer.mask = shapeLayer
     }


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        self.slantedView()

        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColour
        self.backgroundColor?.setFill()
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(rect)

    }
}
```

**This is my custom cell:**

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var statusColour: UIColor = {
        let colour = UIColor.red
        return colour
    }()


    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let statusContainer = SlantedView()
        statusContainer.backgroundColour = self.statusColour
        self.addSubview(statusContainer)

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

}
```

**This is my cellForRow method:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.statusColour = sampleData[indexPath.row].statusColour //Contains different colours

    return cell
}
```

The problem is definitely coming from the UIView subclass. According some prior research, it looks like the `overridden draw function` could be causing the issue.

I followed the advice given in some other Stack Overflow questions by adding these lines:

```
self.backgroundColor?.setFill()
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(rect)
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you show your cellForRowAt?

Comment: @NicolasElPapu I added it.

Comment: change `var statusColour: UIColor = {
        let colour = UIColor.red
        return colour
    }()` to `var statusColour: UIColor = .red` and you are not adding `statusContainer` view  to your cell

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include all of the code to keep the question short. However, I have added the statusContainer to my cell in my code. The table it working fine, and I can set all of my other cell properties without any issues. Your suggestion above didn't make a difference. All my other properties have been set that way and I'm not having issues with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add slantedView in awakeFromNib() method instead of init() and also use property observers to change the backgroung color of slantedView as shown below:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var statusContainer: SlantedView!

    var statusColour: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            guard let color = statusColour else {
                statusContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                return
            }
        statusContainer.backgroundColor = color
       }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        statusContainer = SlantedView(frame: self.bounds)
        self.addSubview(statusContainer)
    }
}
```

Lastly, remove last two lines from draw(_ rect: CGRect) method:-

```
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.slantedView()
    self.backgroundColor = backgroundColour
}
```

Comment: This led me to my answer. The key was declaring statusContainer and statusColour variables the way you did in your example. I also removed all all lines except self.slantedView() from the draw rect function.